# C And C++ Coding Standards

Tags: c++, c, standards

What are best practices with regards to C and C++ coding standards?  Should developers be allowed to willy-nilly mix them together.  Are there any complications when linking C and C++ object files.

Should things like socket libraries that traditionally is written in C remain in C and kept in seperate source files? That is keeping c code in .c files and c++ code in .cpp files.
When mixing c and C++ after being parsed with g++ will there be any performance penalties, since typesafe checks are not done in C? but are in C++.  Would would be the best way to link C and C++ source code files.

Answer (score 7):

The biggest issue is calling a C function from C++ code or vice versa. In that case, you want to make sure you mark the function as having "C" linkage using `extern "C"`. You can do this in the header file directly using:

```
#if defined( __cplusplus )
extern "C" {
#endif

extern int myfunc( const char *param, int another_one );

#if defined( __cplusplus )
}
#endif
```

You need the `#if`s because C code that includes it won't understand `extern "C"`.

If you don't want to (or can't) change the header file, you can do it in the C++ code:

```
extern "C" {
#include "myfuncheader.h"
}
```

You can mark a C++ function as having C linkage the same way, and then you can call it from C code. You can't do this for overloaded functions or C++ classes.

Other than that, there should be no problem mixing C and C++. We have a number of decades-old C functions that are still being used by our C++ code.

Answer (score 3):

C++ doesn't do 'typesafe checks' at run time unless you ask for them (by using `dynamic_cast`). C++ is highly compatible with C, so you may freely call C libraries as you wish and compile C code with a C++ compiler. C++ does not imply 'object-oriented', and you should get no performance penalty from using it.

If you mix code compiled with gcc and with g++, see Graeme's answer.

Comment: Just a detail, but a C++ compiler will compile C with a built-in C compiler.  There are a few things that C does differently from C++.

Comment: Oh yes. I think, though, that the OP is referring to structured, calling-functions-style code as "C code", and my point was that that style is "C++ code" as well; since there's no penalty to using C++, one might as well not worry about the difference and do everything in C++ (not necessarily OOP!).

Answer (score 3):

One should generally assume that c++ can throw exceptions, hence the c wrapper functions in your block, ought to catch them, and morph them into nice error codes that the c caller can digest.

```
extern "c"
{
    int nice_c_function_interface
    (
        void
    )
    {
        int returnStatus;

        try
        {
             returnStatus = nice_cpp_function();
        }
        catch (NiceCppException& that)
        {
             returnStatus = that.failure_code();  
        }
        catch (...)
        {
            cerr << "Oh Worse! an unexpected unknown exception" << endl;

            returnStatus = -1;  // Horrible unknown failure
        }

        return returnStatus;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a function in C++ which calls a function in C which in turn calls another function in C++, and this later function throws an exception which should be caught by the first function, you can have problems unless you told the C compiler to enable generation of the exception handling tables.

For gcc, this is the [`-fexceptions`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.3.2/gcc/Code-Gen-Options.html) parameter, which is enabled by default for C++ but disabled by default for C.

Answer (score 1):

There are no good hard and fast rules here.

If the end product will always be linked with a C++ main() then it does not really matter. As you can always create headers that will do the correct thing.

If you are creating a library that needs to have a C and C++ interface but you can't assume the C++ linker then you will need to make sure you separated the C API from the C++ cleanly. At this point it is usually cleaner to do all the work in C and use C++ classes to proxy to the C.

For example:

```
/* c header */

struct CData
 { /* stuff */ };

void init( CData* data );
void fini( CData* data );
int getSomething( CData* data );
void doSomething( CData* data, int val );

// c++ header

extern "C" {
#include cdata.h
};

class CppData : private CData
 {
 public:
   CppData() { ::init( (CData*)this ); }
   ~CppData() { ::fini( (CData*)this ); }
   int getSomething() { return ::getSomething( (CData*)this ); }
   void doSomething( int val ) { :: doSomething( (CData*)this, val ); }
 };
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you compile all your source with g++ then it is all compiled in C++ object files (i.e. with the appropriate name mangling and the C++ ABI).

You will only need to use the extern "C" trick if you are building libraries that need to be used by explicitly C applications that need to use the C ABI.

If everything is being compiled into a single executable then use g++ and treat everything as C++