# C++ coding standards

Tags: c++, standards

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [C And C++ Coding Standards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/283701/c-and-c-coding-standards)
>   [What existing style and coding standard documents should be used on a C++ project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145570/what-existing-style-and-coding-standard-documents-should-be-used-on-a-c-project)

How to acheive coding standards in C++? Any reference books?

Comment: Not really a duplicate -- that was specifically asking about standards for mixing C and C++.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/145570/what-existing-style-and-coding-standard-documents-should-be-used-on-a-c-project

Comment: @Neil: that one does look like a real duplicate...

Answer (score 6):

You can't afford to ignore [*C++ Coding Standards*](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/c++cs.htm) by Herb Sutter and Andrei Alexandrescu.

Answer (score 2):

Sutter and Alexandrescu, C++ Coding Standards, 220 pgs, Addison-Wesley, 2005, ISBN 0-321-11358-6

is recomended by the C++ FAQ Lite (http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/coding-standards.html)

If you're curious about what sorts of things this book describes, http://www.gotw.ca/publications/c++cs.htm contains a table of contents.

Answer (score 0):

[C++ Coding Standards](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/c++cs.htm) by Sutter and Alexandrescu is very good.

Answer (score 0):

The [C++ FAQ (lite)](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/) has lots of information that is relevant to a coding standard.